# Is there a library function that rounds a number towards the infinities (i.e. away from 0)

Tags: java, math

I need a rounding function that returns a larger integer when the input is positive and the a smaller number when negative, i.e. it should not return 0 unless the input is actually 0.0.

Examples:

```
f(0.1) = 1
f(-0.1) = -1
f(0.0) = 0
```

(The `Math.ceil()` function always rounds up, so `Math.ceil(-0.1) = 0`

Comment: Why not the simpliest approach? If x > 0 Math.ceil, else if x = 0 -> 0, else Math.floor?

Comment: @AndrzejBobak That is what I am doing right now, but it's not very clear in the floor case that you will actually get a smaller number as opposed to the "floor" of the absolute value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
rounded = Math.ceil(Math.abs(toBeRounded)) * Math.signum(toBeRounded);
```

That rounds the absolute value of your number up, then re-applies the signum.

Comment: Much better than my current solution. Thanks!

Comment: `(int) (Math.copySign(Math.ceil(Math.abs(num)), num))` is an even shorter and cheaper alternative I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use ceil and floor as needed.

```
double roundToInfinity = x < 0 ? Math.floor(x) : Math.ceil(x);
```

Note: -0.0 will also round to 0